How many connected shapes can 5 matchsticks create (locked to 90° increments)?
I found an old handmade deck of cards for “Digit”, and the number of cards didn’t match what it said online.
Digit is a game where, each turn, one of 5 matchsticks must be moved, so that it matches the formation on the card that the player wants to discard.
Each card depicts a unique formation of 5 equal-length matchsticks, where they are laid down in 90° increments of rotation, and the formation is contiguous point-to-point. The direction of the head of the matchstick does not matter.
Under Digit rules, reflection and rotation is deemed “the same formation”.
How many total formations can be formed by 5 matchsticks under these rules, ergo, how many cards should a Digit deck contain?
What if Digit disallowed reflections? By how much would the deck grow?
What is the generalized form of this problem/puzzle called (like the matchstick version of polyomino counting)?

Instead of polyominos, they're called polysticks. There is a table there of the number of square polysticks, and it says there are 55 free square pentasticks and 99 one-sided square pentasticks.
